# Convert query in select and group in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am learning `join` tables query generation. I can achieve my goal without `join` table using association. But now my question is how can I get the same result as using `join`, `select` and `group`?

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messsages         
end

class Messsage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Table Structure:**

```
#users : id , first_name , last_name
#messages: id, subject , description , sender_id, recipient_id
```

**Controller:**

```
 @messsages = Messsage.where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
 @sender_list = @messsages.group(:sender_id).count
 => Expected correct output: {1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3} #getting as result
```

by this I am getting from which sender_id I get how much messages. I am using `PostgreSQL`

**My try:**

```
@sender_list = Messsage.joins(:user).select("users.id, users.first_name").group("users.id , messsages.sender_id")
```

**Error:**

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column messsages.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ... "messsages" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "messsages...
                                                             ^
: SELECT users.id, users.first_name FROM "messsages" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "messsages"."user_id" GROUP BY users.id , messsages.sender_id
```

### Update:

I have update my form code also so you may have better idea:

```
<%= form_for(@messsage) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sender_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :sender_id, User.all, :id, :id  %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%=  f.hidden_field :recipient_id , :value => current_user.id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Screenshot of Page:
[image]

Comment: sorry I removed my comment after you edited ur question, makes sense now, I think the problem is in the association, when is a user a recipient and when is he a sender?

Comment: or does one message belong to two people, one as sender and one as recipient?

Comment: When user create message I have taken recipient_id as current_user.id, and user can send msg to any user that time in sender_id column user's id will be inserted.(Here he/she can send them self also which should not be but it's not a concern right now)

Comment: should I update my form's code?

Comment: hold on ill add an answer explaining why you might have a problem

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
class Messsage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Rails is expecting the `messages` table to have a `user_id` field, but it doesn't, it instead has `sender_id` and `recipient_id`, so to make rails understand this you'll need to modify the model a bit

```
class Messsage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
end
```

So now a `Message` has a `sender` and `recipient`.

We can update the `User` model too to understand the difference between sent messages and received messages.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :sender_id
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :recipient_id
end
```

Then your query could be something like

```
current_user.received_messages.group(:sender_id).count
```

Comment: Ok I have change the model's code. My query is I want to group all sender_id with count

Comment: exactly.... I want that for each recipient. after changing in model I get more confused to fire query... So when user login he can get know which user has sent to him how many msgs... got it? or still need more description. :( If I fail to explain

Comment: so like 5 messages from x, 2 messages from y, 3 messages from z

Comment: I tried and got: 
NameError in MesssagesController#index
uninitialized constant User::Message

Comment: is that the rails console or the browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71877/discussion-between-mohammad-abushady-and-hetal-khunti).